# Tapping inside a edittext control doesn't put the caret where I tapped. Anyone know why

Tags: android, onclick, cursor, textview

I have an EditText control on my screen.
When I tap on it, the keyboard shows up, lickety split.
But my carrot is not where I tapped.
The cursor is at the top right...  When I type it of course flows from where the cursor is.

If I tap for just long enough, a little blue triangly thing shows up and I can drag that to where I'd actually want to type.

I don't really know where to go from here.. Is it a setting that lets me set the cursor/carot/insertionpoint :) where I tapped..

As always simpler would be cool.